# Sampling pcollection with dynamic sample count

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I want to sample a static data source using dataflow. I know there is a `Sample` Transform that allows you sample fixed number of data tuple, but what is different in my use case is that my target sample count is dynamic based on actual source size.

I know there is one approach is that I could first count my data source, calculating the probability of my sampling and filter my pcollection using ParDo for which inside each DoFn I flip the coin.

However, one downside is that it seems not very stable especially when my probability is extremely low (for example if I want to pick 50 samples randomly from 500M+ pool).

So I am just wondering, is there any better to do it? (Somehow I feels that it is just some dataflow hacks that I don't know)

---

EDIT:

sorry for the confusion. the problem is that i don't know the size of sources beforehand, they might range from 1M to 500M, and based on my actual size, i want to sample it differently, say my sample size is min(actual_size, 2.5e10/(actual_size)), which makes that when my source size happen to be 500M, i just want 50 of them. and when my actual size is 5M, i want to sample 5000.

In particular, I am wondering:
Is there any built-in `PTranform` that I can use for this particular use case (say can I use `Sample` but just with some workaround?)

Comment: Can you share more details about how you want your sample size to relate to the input size? From your example, it seems like you could just pick a probability that is 50/500M, and that should do what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built-in transform that handles this. The problem is that as your collection gets larger, the function you described actually wants to produce a smaller sample.

There seem to be several ways you could attempt to solve this:

1. Write a custom `CombineFn` that uses a `List` as the accumulator, and builds up the list of the sampled elements. The problem with this approach is that at the worst case, you'll need to have a list of 158113 elements and it would need to fit in memory -- this is likely undesirable.
2. Use a `Count` transform to figure out how many elements are there, and use that as a side-input to a `DoFn` that performs filtering. The `DoFn` can read the side-input to find out the total input size, and then perform a probabilistic sampling based on that.